# Python, Pandas: ¿Como acumulo una columna respetando varias condiciones?

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, bucles

les comento que soy nuevo con Python y Pandas y tengo la siguiente duda:

Dado el siguiente df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Division': [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 
'F.de.Cont': ['01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '01/09/2020','02/09/2020','01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '02/09/2020'],
'Importe': [1000,1500,1000,500,700,2000,1000,6000],
'Acum Diario':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
})
```

Estoy intentando acumular la columna importe en una nueva columna de Acumulado diario que sume todos los elementos de columna importe que sean de una fecha menor o igual y sea de la misma division.
Lo que hice hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
df2=df
for i in df.index:
    for j in df2.index:
        if (df.loc[i,'Division']==df2.loc[j,'Division'] and df2.loc[j,'F.de.Cont']<=df.loc[i,'F.de.Cont']):
            df.loc[i,'Acum Diario']+=df2.loc[j,'Importe']
```

Esto me ha dado el siguiente resultado:

```
Acum Diario  Division   F.de.Cont  Importe
0         3500         2  01/09/2020     1000
1         3500         2  01/09/2020     1500
2         3500         2  01/09/2020     1000
3         4000         2  02/09/2020      500
4         3700         3  01/09/2020      700
5         3700         3  01/09/2020     2000
6         3700         3  01/09/2020     1000
7         9700         3  02/09/2020     6000
```

Funciona, pero tarda mas de 2 hs en ejecutarse, siendo que el df tiene solo 13248 filas.
Sé que iterar dentro de un df no es lo mas recomendado por eso consulto si alguien conoce alguna manera de lograr esto mismo e una forma mas eficiente.

Gracias.

Saludos

Comment: El código que publicó da como resultado: SyntaxError: invalid token

Comment: Querías decir: '01/09/2020', en vez de 01/09/2020, y así?

Comment: Hola @zabop, si exactamente, corregi eso que marcaste y un par de cosas mas, espero se entienda mejor.